# Configuration question: Log only in child, but not in parent?

Tags: .net, log4net

I have got following configuration:

```
<log4net>
    <!--<appenders />-->

    <root />

    <logger name="MyProject">
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="rollingProjectFile" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="MyProject.Jobs">
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="rollingJobsFile" />
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

Both appenders within the two different loggers write to a text-file. Since I would like to have a different text-file for the namespace `MyProject.Jobs`, I defined the second logger. But additionally the same messages are also logged within the parent-logger `MyProject`. How can I achieve a complete separation if I don't want any messages from the child-logger to appear in the parent-logger?

Thx for any tipps
sl3dg3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try:

```
<logger name="MyProject.Jobs" additivity="false">
...
```

Comment: I didn't know about that property, learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can apply a  section to the logger to filter out the child logger.  Though there may be an easier way to accomplish this.

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">  
  <loggerToMatch value="MyProject.Jobs" />  
  <acceptOnMatch value="false" />  
</filter>
```